# Jframe inicia en blanco

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplicación del juego memorama, con socketchannel. El cliente solicita las imágenes al servidor, para poder jugar, pero cuando instancío mi jframe se queda vacío.
Primero tengo un menu donde pido el nombre y la ruta donde se recibirán los archivos. Cuando le doy al botón iniciar, debería instanciar mi tablero con las cartas recibidas, pero por alguna razón se queda en blanco mi jframe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy instanciando el objeto en el momento en el que llegan todos los archivos (solo son 20).
me da la impresión de que como el socketchannel esta en un while(True) nunca termina la ejecución y por eso no permite crear bien el siguiente objeto, pero no se me ocurre que hacer para solucionarlo, si pueden ayudarme, lo agradecería mucho.

```
private void initBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String host = "localhost";
    int puerto = 9000;
    int correctosArchivos = 0;
    direccion = fieldAddress.getText() + "/imagenes";

    try {
        InetSocketAddress dst = new InetSocketAddress(host, puerto);
        SocketChannel cl = SocketChannel.open();

        cl.configureBlocking(false);
        Selector sel = Selector.open();
        cl.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
        cl.connect(dst);
        while (true) {
            sel.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> it = sel.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey k = (SelectionKey) it.next();

                it.remove();
                if (k.isConnectable()) {

                    SocketChannel ch = (SocketChannel) k.channel();

                    if (ch.isConnectionPending()) {
                        System.out.println("Estableciendo conexion con el servidor... espere..");

                        try {
                            ch.finishConnect();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }//catch

                        System.out.println("Conexion establecida...\n");
                    }//if
                    //una vez establecida la conexion se agrega al selector mi canal y se le pone lo de leer y escirbir
                    ch.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    continue;
                }//if
                if (k.isReadable()) {
                    SocketChannel ch = (SocketChannel) k.channel();

                    if (verificarArchivos && correctosArchivos < 21) {
                        if (flagDir) {
                            File carpeta = new File(fieldAddress.getText() + "/imagenes");
                            carpeta.mkdir();
                            flagDir = false;
                        }
                        String nameImg = "" + String.valueOf(correctosArchivos) + ".jpg";
                        Path path = Paths.get(direccion + "/" + nameImg);
                        FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(path, EnumSet.of(
                                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE));

                        //Recivimos el tama?o de la imagen
                        ByteBuffer tempB = ByteBuffer.allocate(5);
                        tempB.clear();
                        int n = ch.read(tempB);
                        tempB.flip();
                        String sizeI = new String(tempB.array(), 0, n);
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                        buffer.clear();
                        int auxTamImg = 0;
                        while (ch.read(buffer) > 0 || auxTamImg < Integer.valueOf(sizeI)) {
                            auxTamImg++;
                            buffer.flip();
                            fileChannel.write(buffer);
                            //buffer.clear();
                            buffer.compact();
                        }
                        fileChannel.close();
                        if (correctosArchivos == 20) {
                            pedirArchivos = false;



                            tablero = new tablero(direccion, username.getText());
                            tablero.setVisible(true);
                            this.dispose();




                        }
                        correctosArchivos++;
                    }
                } else if (k.isWritable()) {
                    SocketChannel ch = (SocketChannel) k.channel();
                    if (pedirArchivos) {
                        String pedir = "solImagenes";
                        byte[] envio = pedir.getBytes();
                        ByteBuffer b2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(envio);
                        ch.write(b2);
                        verificarArchivos = true;
                        k.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    }

                    //if      
                    continue;
                } //if

            }

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(initPlayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

Comment: si haces un `while (true) ` es por que necesitas iterara (Recorrer un objeto de tamaño indefinido); te recomendaria iterar el mismo objeto hasta que no tenga mas datos el solo finaliza.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/iterate-through-objects/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600724/how-to-iterate-through-list-of-object-arrays

Comment: había probado con una bandera, para que cuando ya no reciba mas datos, el while se haga falso, pero aun asi sigue instanciando en blanco el siguiente jframe